# How to install gtkesc,gtklev and gtk4dg?

Tags: gtk

I want to install rw05 in my ubuntu. In the readme file they are recommending this packages over other version. Is there any way to find them or to compile them?

Comment: gtkesc,gtklev and gtk4dg appear to be programs provided by the rw05 package itself, built by executing `make gtk` in the `rw05/src` directory